# I get Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appartment') while the filed exists and data type matches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios

I get this error from my axios  post request  **Error message: {error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appartment')"}** while the sent data is exactly what should be sent.. I test the api with the same data and it works but the client side doesn't work .

This is my request  :

```
async function postData() {
    const requestData = {
      User: "642ab5c99f9ad0ae266a8391",
      appartment: "642187183d7a4584d959d063",
      description: "my reservation",
      checkIn: "2023-04-12",
      checkOut: "2023-04-24",
      servicesFee: 150,
      nightsFee: 650,
      services: ["641c363db26efcbc26b02faa", "641c37ee8478c385e59bf27a"],
    };
  
    console.log("Request data:", requestData);
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:9090/user/reservations/createOrder",
        requestData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      console.log("Response data:", response.data);
      // Handle success
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error message:", error.response.data);
      // Handle error
    }
  }
```

and this is the body sent by postman to the same endpoint :

```
{
  
  "Order": {
    "User" : "642ab5c99f9ad0ae266a8391",
    "appartment":"642187183d7a4584d959d063",
    "description": "my reservation ",
    "checkIn": "2023-04-12",
    "checkOut": "2023-04-24",
    "servicesFee": 150,
    "nightsFee": 650,
    "services": [
        "641c363db26efcbc26b02faa",
        "641c37ee8478c385e59bf27a"
    ]
  }
 
}
```

I'm sure that it's not a typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should put your *requestData* into a **Order** object.
same as the body that sent from the postman

```
const requestData = { 
  Order : {
      User: "642ab5c99f9ad0ae266a8391",
      appartment: "642187183d7a4584d959d063",
      description: "my reservation",
      checkIn: "2023-04-12",
      checkOut: "2023-04-24",
      servicesFee: 150,
      nightsFee: 650,
      services: ["641c363db26efcbc26b02faa", "641c37ee8478c385e59bf27a"],
  }
};
```